# How do I cleanly shutdown server when IIS is restarted or App Pool is recycled?

Tags: c++, iis, webserver, winsock

I'm writing a server app using Winsock that is registered with IIS using the httpPlatformHandler module.

It seems to be working fine so far. I'm wondering how I should change my code to allow it to shut down cleanly. Currently I have to start Task Manager and kill my program and the App Pool.

Comment: Why do you need to kill it? Are threads stuck in your app?

Comment: I need to deploy a new version of the exe when I make changes.

Comment: Can you do a quick test like this? 1. Trigger a request to your server app, so that you can see `w3wp.exe` and your `app.exe` (and their process IDs) in Task Manager or Process Explorer. 2. Recycle this application pool in IIS Manager. Wait for a while and see if the old `w3wp.exe` and `app.exe` exit peacefully. Unless the old `w3wp.exe` and `app.exe` hang there forever, you need to take further action to resolve the issue. Otherwise, your code is already good enough.

Comment: When I Recycle the App Pool, a new w3wp.exe starts and after about 5 seconds the old w3wp.exe and my app.exe exit.

Comment: I have one other question. How do I access posted data? If I send data with the GET method, I only see the headers when calling recv. If I use POST, I don't see the headers.

Comment: I have replied to you in your question which asked in Q&A community.